# "A referral was returned from the server"..install certificate to Trusted store?

Tags: delphi, installation, certificate, inno-setup, ui-automation

I'm new to code signing...

I've developed a Windows UI Automation application in Delphi 2007 that has `UIAccess=True` in its manifest, and has to be code signed and installed to the System32 folder to satisfy Microsoft's security requirements for UI Automation--so that it can run under a Standard user Windows login.

During testing we self-signed the executable using a certificate generated by MakeCert, manually added the certificate to the Trusted Root Certificates store, and it all worked fine.

Yesterday we received our actual certificate from Comodo. I can sign the executable with no problems--the .EXE file's properties show all the certificate information, intact.

But when I install the file to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (the 32-bit System32 redirect), login with a Standard user account, and run the application I get the *A referral was returned from the server* error message. (It runs fine with an Administrative login, however.)

So what am I missing? Looking for the certificate in the Trusted Root Certificates store I don't find it. Is that why I can't run the executable from a Standard login? If so, how do I add my software's certificate to the Trusted store on machines where the software gets installed? (I'm using Inno Setup to build the installer.)

Or is the problem something else entirely?

EDIT:  ...SOLVED...

I discovered this problem was rooted mostly in lack of understanding:  I was signing and protecting my .EXE in the wrong order (duh, protect with Armadillo first, sign last!). 
But as often happens, part of my confusion stemmed from an unrelated minor bug which made things seem to be other than what they were.

What bug? In Inno Setup in the `[Files]` section, when a 32-bit install is running on a 64-bit system, the `{sys}` constant resolves to C:\Windows\SysWOW64. But in the `[Icons]` section `{sys}` resolves to C:\Windows\System32...which gets applied to shortcut Targets.

Windows is still able to use that Target for invoking .EXEs (apparently it does a redirect when the link is invoked), but the link itself (Start menu link or desktop icon) ends up with a generic icon, not the one in the .EXE.

*...I have submitted a bug report to Jordan Russell.*

Comment: Where have you reported the issue ? I'm asking because there is [`a place for reporting issues`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues) and I'm not sure if Jordan still works on Inno Setup.

Comment: @TLama: Thanks for that! The JRSoftware site mentions contacting him (email) about bugs; I didn't know to look on GitHub. I'll post there.